# Using JSDoc how would I annotate a destructured renamed function argument?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, destructuring

ES6 syntax allows to rename destructured variables and arguments.

Variables:

```
const {requestID: _requestID, notifyChanges: _notifyChanges} = someObject;
console.log(_requestID, _notifyChanges);
```

Arguments:

```
/**
 * Creates a cloud ready request.
 * @param {String} requestID Request ID used for for tracing and logs
 * @param {Boolean} [notifyChanges] Send an event to the message queue.
 */
function createRequest({
  requestID: _requestID,
  notifyChanges: _notifyChanges = false,
}) {
  console.log(_requestID, _notifyChanges);
});
```

Even though the JavaScript code above is valid, the JSDoc shows errors saying:
`Parameter 'requestID' described in JSDoc does not appear in function signature`

How would I properly annotate a **descructured and renamed** function argument in JSDoc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use colon in JSDoc parameter name:

```
/**
 * Creates a cloud ready request.
 * @param {String} _requestID:requestID Request ID used for for tracing and logs
 * @param {Boolean} [_notifyChanges:notifyChanges] Send an event to the message queue.
 */
function createRequest({
  requestID: _requestID,
  notifyChanges: _notifyChanges = false,
}) {
  console.log(_requestID, _notifyChanges);
});
```

This was tested in WebStorm IDE 2016.2. Works fine.